# Solve $(z+2) /( z-3i) = 4+2i$ for $z$ in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having some trouble trying to isolate $z$. Can I multiply $(4+2i)$ by $(z-3i)$ without changing $z$ into standard form?

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: Algebra (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) in the complex numbers works exactly like algebra in the real numbers, except that you have the additional relation $i^2 = -1$.  You can add, subtract, multiply whatever you want; you can divide as long as you're not dividing by $0$.

Comment: how do you solve $\frac{x+2}{x-3} = 4?$

Answer (score 2):

$$(z+2)=(4+2i)(z-3i)=(4+2i)z-12i+6\\z+2=4z+2iz-12i+6\\3z+2iz=12i-4\\z=\frac{12i-4}{3+2i}=...=\frac {12} {13}+\frac {44} {13} i$$

Comment: How did you go from 4z to 2z and from 2iz to 6iz?

Comment: @Filip maybe a typo, edited